# Fastest method to modify bytestring over loop in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, byte

I have an image stored as a bytestring `b''` and am performing per-pixel operations. Right now the fastest way I've found is to use the `struct` crate to pack and unpack the bytes during modification, then save the pixels to a `bytearray`

```py
# retrieve image data. Stored as bytestring
pixels = buff.get(rect, 1.0, "CIE LCH(ab) alpha double",
                  Gegl.AbyssPolicy.CLAMP)
# iterator split into 32-byte chunks for each pixel's 8-byte LCHA channels
pixels_iter = (pixels[x:x + 32] for x in range(0, len(pixels), 32))
new_pixels = bytearray()

# when using `pool.map`, the loop was placed in its own function.
for pixel in pixels_iter:
    l, c, h, a = struct.unpack('dddd', pixel)
    # simple operation for now: lower chroma if bright and saturated
    c = c - (l * c) / 100
    new_pixels += struct.pack('dddd', l, c, h, a)

# save new data. everything hereout handled by GEGL instead of myself.
shadow.set(rect, "CIE LCH(ab) alpha double", bytes(new_pixels))
```

Problem is this takes about 3 1/2 seconds for a 7MP image on my workstation. Fair but not ideal if updates are frequently requested. From what I've gathered, it seems the constant array modification and possibly struct [un]packing are the main culprits. I've refactored this probably a dozen times and I think I'm out of ideas for optimizing this.

I've tried:

- `struct.unpack`ing the whole bytestring once instead of each pixel as-needed. Lost about 20% efficiency.
- `collections.deque` Admittedly not familiar with its technicalities. Lost 10-30% depending on implementation

  - similar results with other iterator helpers like `map`/`join`
- `numpy.array` Also admittedly know basically nothing about general numpy. Similar results to deque
- `multiprocessing` seemed to be bottlenecked when I appended the `pool.map` results to `new_pixels`. Actually lost about 10% which seems wild, as usually I can just lazily throw threads at problems. The `pixels_iter` was grouped *again* into equally sized sublists for each thread, so `new_pixels` concatenated 8 large lists instead of a few million small lists, which I thought would be faster. Tempted to retry this one as I might've botched it somehow with my 4 am implementation.

  - In theory it could also work by saving multiple small sections of the image buffer to avoid concatenating to `new_pixels` entirely, but that would vastly increase code complexity elsewhere.
- Converting `pixels` itself into a `bytearray` and modifying it in-place using slice ranges. Lost ~30% but also halved memory usage.

Completely separate interpreters like Pypy are off the table, as I'm not the one bundling the Python version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy should produce much faster results than a manual loop, if you use it properly. Using it properly means using NumPy operations over whole arrays, not just looping manually over a NumPy array.

For example,

```
new_pixels = bytearray(pixels)

as_numpy = numpy.frombuffer(new_pixels, dtype=float)
as_numpy[1::4] *= 1 - as_numpy[::4] / 100
```

Now `new_pixels` contains the adjusted values.